# Файловый менеджер для YII

Tags: jquery, редактор-текста, php, yii

Здравствуйте. Установил я связку **CKeditor + Eflinder** на свой YII (процесс решение этой задачи был не из веселых). Теперь не могу прицепить тот же **elfinder** к `input`. Оказалось что этот **elfinder** вроде как староват и документацией не блещет. Честно говоря оф. сайт вообще не отвечает.

Вопрос: как подцепить **eflidner** к `input`? Или, пожалуйста, посоветуйте мне другой `file manager`, который садится на `YII` на раз два.

Еще такой вопрос: Я не пользовал **imperavi redactor**, но как я понял в него вшит отличный `file manager`. Можно ли этот `file manager` присандалить отдельно на тот же `input`?

Всем спасибо.

Comment: **imperavi** еще есть. Попробуйте, так на заметку. Для Yii бесплатный.

Answer (score 1):

- https://bitbucket.org/z_bodya/yii-tinymce
- https://bitbucket.org/z_bodya/yii-elfinder

Думаю так же будут полезны вот эти ссылки:

- http://www.cervic.info/2011/05/yii-i-tinymceelfinder/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/newtinymce/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/elfinder/

Можно объединить, я делал так в `_form`

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content');?>
    <?php $this->widget('ext.tinymce.TinyMce', array(
         'model' => $model,
         'attribute' => 'content',
         // Optional config
         'compressorRoute' => 'tinyMce/compressor',
         //'spellcheckerUrl' => array('tinyMce/spellchecker'),
         // or use yandex spell: http://api.yandex.ru/speller/doc/dg/tasks/how-to-spellcheck-tinymce.xml
         'spellcheckerUrl' => 'http://speller.yandex.net/services/tinyspell',
         'fileManager' => array(
             'class' => 'ext.elfinder.TinyMceElFinder',
             'connectorRoute'=>'elfinder/connector',
         ),
         'language'=>'ru',
         'htmlOptions' => array(
             'rows' => 6,
             'cols' => 60,
         ),
     ));
     echo $form->error($model,'content') ?><br />
</div>
```

Привязка к инпуту

```
$this->widget('ext.elFinder.ServerFileInput', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'image',
        'connectorRoute' => 'elfinder/connector',
    )
);
```