# Yii: ошибка записи в свойство

Tags: php, yii

Прикручиваю [расширение](https://github.com/pomidorchik/JCKEditorWidget) для CKEditor на Yii
На этапе подключения [SmartClientScript](https://github.com/pomidorchik/SmartClientScript), возникло исключение:

```
Свойство "CWebApplication.clientScript" доступно только для чтения.
```

Хз как это возможно, если свойство CWebApplication.clientScript определено [для чтения и записи](http://pear.php.net/package/PhpDocumentor/docs/latest/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html):

```
@property CClientScript $clientScript The client script manager.
```

Вопросов два:

1. Как это мого случится?
2. Подскажите, если знаете, более грамотное расширение для CKEditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или я плохо понял концепцию Yii или вы связываете в принципе несвязываемые вещи.

```
@property CClientScript $clientScript The client script manager.
```

используется исключительно для документации (кроме случая [аспектно-ориентированного программирования](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170021/)). Интерпретатор PHP сюда даже не заглядывает (если не ошибаюсь, он вообще все комментарии удаляет).

Я бы **предположил**, что ваша проблема состоит в том, что регистрация компонента, якобы указанного в `CWebApplication::clientScript`, на самом деле жестко вписана в метод `CWebApplication::registerCoreComponents()`

```
'clientScript'=>array(
    'class'=>'CClientScript',
)
```

Тогда как вариант костыля, можно было бы унаследовать класс `CWebApplication` и в наследнике определить метод

```
protected function registerCoreComponents()
{
    parent::registerCoreComponents();

    $components=array(
        'clientScript'=>array(
            'class'=>'CClientScript',
        )
    );

    $this->setComponents($components);
}
```

---

Но вместо этого я **настоятельно рекомендую** воспользоваться [инструкцией](https://github.com/pomidorchik/SmartClientScript#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) для подключения. Только что проверил: создал папочку для расширений, положил туда в подпапку `SmartClientScript` php файл, добавил строки

```
'clientScript' => array(
    'class'=>'ext.SmartClientScript.SmartClientScript',
),
```

в файл `protected/config/main.php` в массив `components`. Все заработало без ошибок.

В конечном итоге редактор отобразился. Пробуйте :-)

З.Ы. Заглядывайте в лог ошибок, возможно там найдете подсказку.

**UPD** Сам редактор взял [отсюда](http://ckeditor.com/download) и положил в папочку `ckeditor4` в корне проекта. При подключении [виджета](https://github.com/pomidorchik/JCKEditorWidget) использовал код, приведенный в примере [readme.md](https://github.com/pomidorchik/JCKEditorWidget/blob/master/readme.md)

Comment: @Johny вот слово "компонент" я как раз и пропустил в инструкции. Теперь работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Johny а при добавлении компонента clientScript у вас тоже отвалились стили оформления?

Comment: @Johny последний вопрос снят.  Компонент clientScript уже был заюзан выше в коде конфига.

Answer (score 0):

Если не обязателен `CKEditor`, то есть `TinyMce`

[Файловый менеджер для YII](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242477/?focusedAnswerId=242588#242588)

Comment: @Алим если не выгорит с CKEditor, то попробую ваш вариант.